# chrome extension occurs multiple times in Task Manager

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Sometimes my extension stops working (clicking the browser action doesn't do anything, it stops doing its background activites). I'm debugging that problem.

When it stops working, if I click 'background.html' to open the background page, I get a blank white window instead of the background page (none of the panels open). Reloading the extension from 'chrome://extensions' doesn't allow me to get the background page either. I have to completely quit the browser and restart. If I keep the background page open and then the extension stops working, the JS console doesn't work. I can't use the 'Sources' tab to find out what stack frames are executing etc.

I also noticed that the extension occurs multiple times (multiple adjacent rows) in Google Chrome's own task manager. But I'm unable to select them individually. Clicking one row selects them all.

Anybody seen this before?

Could this occur if my extension code gets into an endless loop? I don't see high CPU usage either at the OS level or in Google Chrome's task manager. Same behavior under both Mac and Linux.

FWIW the extension is relatively complex: it uses web workers, 10s of uploads and downloads in the background page.